# CakePHP: Cant do Simple Login

Tags: php, cakephp

i'm starting to cook cake haha, everytime that i submit my form for to make the authentication, nothing happens!

This's my AppController

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
            'DebugKit.Toolbar',
            'Session',
            'Auth' => array(
                'authenticate' => array(
                    'Form' => array(
                        'fields' => array(
                            'username' => 'email',
                            'password' => 'senha'
                        ),

                    )
                ),
                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home'),
                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'),
                'authError' => 'Sorry, You Can not Access it!',
                'loginError' => 'Login or Password incorrets!',
                'autoRedirect' => false
    ));


}
```

My Model User

```
class User extends AppModel
{

    public $name ="User";
public function beforeSave($options = array()){
                if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['senha'])){
                    $this->data[$this->alias]['senha'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['senha']);
                }
            return true;    
    }

}
```

just it, without validations! So My UsersControllers

```
    class UsersController extends AppController
{

    public $name = "Users";

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('adicionar'); 
    }

    public function index(){

    }

    public function home(){
        $this->render('/home');
    }

    public function login(){    
        if($this->request->is('post')){ 
            debug($this->request->data);
            die();  
            if($this->Auth->login()){
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Mail or Password incorrets, Try again!'));
            }
        }   
    }

    public function adicionar(){
         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $this->User->create();
                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
        }
    }

}
```

how you can see, the action login is rendering the view Login, Is there any problem??

And My View Login for authentication..

```
  <?php echo $this->Form->create('User',array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')));    
          echo $this->Form->input('email');
      echo $this->Form->input('senha');
      echo $this->Form->submit('Login');
   echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Where am i my wrong? I cann't authenticate..

Updating....

How I had said, debuggin my project i can see! My request data is no empty

[image]

but i fell conditional else

[image]

Debug Request Data

[image]

Comment: can you comment this line ($this->render('/login');) to see what is going on?...Did you load App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component'); on top of your AppController

Comment: actually, I could understand how to work views, i just created a folder "Users" inside view, /View/Users and the login.ctp, the action search a view that has the same name! 

Right, i dont load, but i thought that was set $component = 'Auth'

Comment: the folder that you are created(Users) should be => (users) and Auth doesn't have any thing to do with your views

Comment: The folder's name cannot be Uppercase?

Comment: will be my problem is name folder? Is in upercas

Comment: Users in view has to be users - in lowersace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//AppController

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class AppController extends Controller {

    /** 
     * Components
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'senha'
                    ),

                )
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'),
            'authError' => 'Por favor, Faça o login para acessar a Área Restrita',
            'loginError' => 'Login ou Senha incorreto!'
            'autoRedirect' => false
    );
```

view - You have to set Model name User NOT Users in create form

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User',array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')); 
         echo $this->Form->input('email');
          echo $this->Form->input('senha');
   echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

//controller

```
public function login()
    {

        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            if($this->Auth->login())
            {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }else
            {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your username/password was incorrect');
            }
        }

    }
```

//add this to your User model

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * User Model
 */
class User extends AppModel {        

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

                if (!empty($this->data['User']['password'])) {
                    $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
                } 
                return true;
            }
}
```

here is the [Simple Auth login](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)

Comment: Not work! "the screen just flashes", it sends the data.. I have DebugKit, Do you want some information?

Comment: Just now updated the answer if it doesn't work . give me more info plz

Comment: well, it sends, i receive data (email, senha), its not empty, but i'm not redirected! Debuggin my project, in Session -> Flash, i receive a msg (Password or Username Incorrets!) so i'm fell in my else

Comment: which hashing are you using? If your password in database is only string it is better and secure to hash your password before store in DB - just updated my answer - try to edit your user modify the password field

Comment: well, the hashing is AuthComponent::password. Did you see my updating of debug?

Comment: if you follow this article you will be able to fix it http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Comment: do you have your project live some where live to test?

Comment: no :\ is localhost! Man i already read, but how my columns are differents i did that way, so.. i'm falling in my condition "Else" this object "$this->Auth->login()" is empty?? why, my resquest data is  with datas

Comment: can you do debug($this->request->data); die; in login action give me the print.

Comment: I think that the problem be hash no?

Comment: might be you have have save hash in db then you can check the login

Comment: yeah, in database my password is "hashed", so for check login i need pass anything?

Comment: :'( what would be my problem?

Comment: zip your app folder (AppController, UserController, UserModel, login-edit User view) send to my email let me look at it

Comment: I see only the linkedin :3

Comment: isaac(dot)rajaei(at)gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here

```
public function beforeFilter()
{       
    $this->Auth->fields = array(
            'username' => 'email',
            'password' => 'senha'
        );
}
```

try this

```
  public function beforeFilter()
    { 
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(          
                    'Form' => array(
                        'fields' => array(
                            'username' => 'email',
                            'password' => 'senha'
                                )
                            )
                        )
    }
```

**@@@ UPDATE @@@@ **

Well, at last i got the solution...i think so......

The problem is on your View. Use this-

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User',array('action'=>'login')); ?>
    <div class="input">
      <div class="blockinput">
        <i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>
        <input type="mail" name="email" placeholder="Email">

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('type' => 'email', 'placeholder' => 'Email', 'label' => false));?>

      </div>
      <div class="blockinput">
        <i class="icon-unlock"></i>

       <?php echo $this->Form->input('senha', array('type' => 'password', 'placeholder' => 'Senha', 'label' => false));?>

      </div>
    </div>
       <button>Entrar</button>
  <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Comment: Man, i'm not getting make a simple login, I've signed up a user, thinking that it would be the problem, I thought that framework only recognize it if it had been registered with their Auth options..

Comment: Actually, i think you didn't read well the Cakephp documentation.  Don't be depress, carry on. Its a nice and powerfull framework.

Comment: Is it worked after changing the login.ctp?
You are getting array like
`array(
     'email' => '-----',
     'sehna' => '-----'
)`

but this should be looks like
`array(
    'User' => array(
     'email' => '-----',
     'sehna' => '-----'
    )
)`

Comment: is not working, i'm falling inside ELSE, returning this session flash Session->setFlash('Your username/password was incorrect')

Comment: It will work bcz i tested here... I would like to see the present condition of application. Update your question with present UsersController, AppController, User model and login.ctp

Comment: Man, again problem in View...... Edit this two line on login.ctp

`echo $this->Form->input('username', array('type'=>'email', 'name'=>'email'));
          echo $this->Form->input('password'); `

should be as 

'echo $this->Form->input('email');
          echo $this->Form->input('sehna');`