# CakePHP Auth->login() function not working

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, authorization

having problems with this function. Currently I've set up my website so the What's On and Offers page are only accessible after a user logs in. If they click on these pages they're redirected to the login page.

Unfortunately when the user goes to login, the login page is just refreshed instead of signing them in and redirecting them to the index page.

My Users table has the following fields: user_id, firstname, surname, email, password, created, modified.

This is my code for the login function which is in UsersController:

```
public function login() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
```

This is my code for the AppController:

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {


        public $helpers = array(
                'Session',
                'Html' => array('className' => 'BoostCake.BoostCakeHtml'),
                'Form' => array('className' => 'BoostCake.BoostCakeForm'),
                'Paginator' => array('className' => 'BoostCake.BoostCakePaginator'),
        );

    // CakePHP documentation tutorial
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'pages',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ),
            'flash' => array(
                'element' => 'alert',
                'key' => 'auth',
                'params' => array(
                    'plugin' => 'BoostCake',
                    'class' => 'alert-error'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'contact');
    }

}
```

This is my code for login.ctp :

```
<!-- Sign in Form which is on the left hand side of the screen -->
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
            'inputDefaults' => array(
                'action' => 'login',
                'div' => 'form-group',
                'label' => array(
                    'class' => 'col col-md-3 control-label'
                    ),
                'wrapInput' => 'col col-md-9',
                'class' => 'form-control'
                ),
                'class' => 'well form-horizontal'
            )); ?>

            <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
                'placeholder' => 'Email'
            )); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
                'placeholder' => 'Password'
            )); ?>

            <!-- Sign in button for the sign in form -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Sign in', array(
                    'div' => 'col col-md-9 col-md-offset-3',
                    'class' => 'btn btn-default'
                ));
                echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <h5 small><?php echo $this->Html->link("Not registed? Click here to register!", '/users/register') ?></h5>
            </div>
```

Hopefully someone could point out what's going wrong

Answer (score 1):

you are not posting your data to your controller and action. Try this on create:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User',
                        array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
                        'inputDefaults' => array(
                            'div' => 'form-group',
                            'label' => array(
                                'class' => 'col col-md-3 control-label'
                                ),
                            'wrapInput' => 'col col-md-9',
                            'class' => 'form-control'
                            ),
                            'class' => 'well form-horizontal'
                        )); ?>
```

Create a CackPHP Login button

```
echo $this->Form->end(__('Login'));
```

you might find this use full
[CakePHP: Cant do Simple Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748215/cakephp-cant-do-simple-login/22757738#22757738)

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? Try using redirectUrl rather than redirect() on this part since you should use that after version 2.3.:

```
return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
```

If it does not help, try putting some echo's to see if $this->Auth->login() is true and what the value of $this->Auth->redirect() is. If everything seems normal, try to see if the flash message actually gets outputted by your view (in case the auth->login is false).

The code seems fine, so you really have to debug some steps to actually work towards a solution.

Comment: Using CakePHP 2.4.6, will try this out now!

Comment: This doesn't work either, how do you debug in CakePHP?

Comment: Simply putt something like echo $this->Auth->redirect() or print_r($this->Auth->redirect());  followed by an exit; Even stuff like echo "I'm now here"; will give you some insights where the script is.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. Please read more here [Configuring Authentication handlers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: What's the 'username' and 'email' variables supposed to be? Is 'username' the model?

Comment: Normally you authenticate with username and password, in your portal you want authenticate with email, so you need to change authenticate field from username to email.

Comment: So mine should be 'email' => 'password' yes? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: By default is :`'fields' => array('username' => 'username')` in your case is `'fields' => array('username' => 'email')`. Because for login you use email **instead** of username

Answer (score 0):

Its because you forget something to add on your Components setting- You public $components have to looks like this-

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email'
                )
            )
        ),
        'flash' => array(
            'element' => 'alert',
            'key' => 'auth',
            'params' => array(
                'plugin' => 'BoostCake',
                'class' => 'alert-error'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: do you defined `public $primaryKey` on User.php model?