# Cakephp auth is not working on production

Tags: cakephp, authentication

Guys I uploaded my site on servers and I'm facing this problem.

**Usercontroller.php**

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Users';
    var $components = array('Auth', 'Acl');


    function beforeFilter(){
        //parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->loginError = "asdad!";
        $this->Auth->authError = "sdsd !.";
        App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'User';
        $this->Auth->allow('login','register','login','step2','TakeId','kontakt');
    }
    function login(){
        if(!empty($this->data)){
            $this->request->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password']);
            $sprawdz = $this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('User.username'=>$this->request->data['User']['username'],'User.password'=>$this->request->data['User']['password'])));
            echo debug($sprawdz);
            if(!empty($sprawdz)){
                if($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)){
                    $this->redirect('/');
                    echo debug('you are log in!') ; 
                    } 
            }
            else {
                $this->User->invalidate('username', 'mistake!');
            } 
        }
    }

    function logout(){
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

User/login.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');
              echo $this->Form->input('password'); ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Log in')); ?>
```

It is like Auth does not work at all. In localhost was fine. Additionaly, users/index is empty page :)

Any ideas would be great. Thanks.

Comment: your cakephp version? Always try to indicate that on your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP: Cant do Simple Login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748215/cakephp-cant-do-simple-login)

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple, and [follow the tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout) which shows how to use the auth component.

For example, try this:

```
function login(){
     if ($this->request->is('post')) {    
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
               $this->Session->setFlash('You have successfully logged in the system');
               return $this->redirect('/');
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again [warning]'));
        }
}
```

Also please make sure [Security.Salt](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-AuthComponent.html#_password) which is responsible to hash a password with the application's salt value

You did not defined any index function in usersController, that is why it is throwing error. Try to enable debug mode on so that you can track the errors

Answer (score 0):

add $this->request->data on 2nd line of your login aciton-

```
function login(){
    if(!empty($this->request->data)){
        $this->request->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        $sprawdz = $this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('User.username'=>$this->request->data['User']['username'],'User.password'=>$this->request->data['User']['password'])));
        echo debug($sprawdz);
        if(!empty($sprawdz)){
            if($this->Auth->login()){
                $this->redirect('/');
                echo debug('you are log in!') ; 
                } 
        }
        else {
           $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password');
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I use CakePhp 2.0 ;P, anyway I have good ask to sql, but Auth->login doesn't work

Comment: Your code is totally messed.. How you are hashing password when registering a new user? Why you are using find condition on login action while Auth component can take care of all those thing....?

Comment: @user2761717 it "doesn't work" because you manually find a user, destroy the request data, and then ask the auth component to login using the (destroyed) request data; the auth component will be hashing the password again.